# Unknown characters in Telegram windows app

Tags: windows, telegram-messenger

I am using telegram messenger in windows os.(Windows app)
I see many messages like below :

[image: Unknown characters]

What are those characters and how can i fix this problem?
Is this problem related to font or UT8?

---

**Here is copy paste of that text after comments :**

✅✅✅  
  //
  
 
   
✅✅✅,,       
    ✅
 10$/
HLR Validated - $12$/k
   50 �

---

It works here - So strange.
It is bold - Italic.
Why my telegram can not show them?

Comment: We can't tell you what might be wrong with it because all we have is a picture. Copy/paste of the actual text as well might help. Could be missing font or substitution error.

Comment: Here is piece of that text :    50 

Comment: That text works here - So strange.

Comment: That pasting the information into another place works suggests that the Telegram app is not properly supporting unicode or is using a non-unicode font, spammers regularly abuse unicode characters to get around spam filters. I'd just delete it and move on.

Comment: I am in windows 10 os - supporting both EN and AR languages. By the way thanks for helping me. I did edit my question. Remember i have problem for some text in telegram - Not all of the them. Most of them are ok in en language.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the comments - How can force telegram to read them? The owner of that post can read it in telegram - So i should can read it.

Comment: The fonts I see here are Deja Vu Sans Bold Oblique, Deja Vu Sans Book & Helvetica Neue.  Of course, anybody who uses emojis & text like that in advertising isn't worth reading anyway… so count yourself lucky ;)) You have a font substitution issue by the looks of it - if it's not handing over to the system correctly, you might need to raise it as a bug with the applications devs.

Comment: That it is doing bold and italic without "normal" formatting characters points firmly at unicode alternatives being used. Does Telegram let you change the font used in it? If not then there's not much you can do. As Tetsujin says it's a font substitution issue that only the devs can really fix, or you can stop reading spam....

Comment: How did you recognize those font names? Is there any trick for that?

Comment: I just copy/pasted bits into a word processor

Comment: My word can show those characters - It means there is a font in my system that can work with those characters. I think telegram should act like word.

Comment: "should" & "does" are two entirely separate things. It's likely only the devs can fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text you are being sent was encoded by either a crazy person
or someone who managed to completely misunderstand Unicode.

This is what I see in the clipboard when copying the first line of your
text:

[image]

For example, the characters D835 and DE4F are
[Unicode Surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates)
defined as:

> The UCS uses surrogates to address characters outside the initial
> Basic Multilingual Plane without resorting to more-than-16-bit byte
> representations.[10] There are 1024 "high" surrogates (D800–DBFF) and
> 1024 "low" surrogates (DC00–DFFF). By combining a pair of surrogates,
> the remaining characters in all the other planes can be addressed
> (1024 × 1024 = 1048576 code points in the other 16 planes). In UTF-16,
> they must always appear in pairs, as a high surrogate followed by a
> low surrogate, thus using 32 bits to denote one code point.
>
> A surrogate pair denotes the code point
>
> [image]
>
> where H and L are the numeric values of the high and low surrogates
> respectively.

In short, that crazy sender encoded each 16-bit Unicode character as two
16-bit surrogates that together give one character!

I really don't blame Telegram for failing to display the text.
It requires an excellent implementation of Unicode for any program
to correctly display it.

Comment: Thanks for the pro answer. There many similar apps like telegram that are using telegram api. I think sender is using those apps and this is why my original telegram can't handle it.
In these days i saw many group titles like those strange characters.

Comment: Nothing crazy though. Your hex editor has problems with “line breaks”, that’s all. Keep in mind that what you see in the question is not the original encoding but rather what Stack Exchange serves. // The first character for example is a “MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL T”, the L of _Loyalty_ is a “MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL L”.

Comment: Ahhh… mathematicals - the later text copy/paste didn't grok that. Mathematicals are **always** a bugger to substitute.

Comment: @DanielB: You're right, this is 32-bit code, not 16-bit. The problem was my interpretation, not my clipboard dumper (not hex editor). Although I think that you should agree that these Unicode kiddos are at least a bit weird and problematic.

Answer (score 3):

Those characters are not regular letters but rather come from different blocks of Unicode.

The bold italic text (like ) is from the *Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols* block, specifically consisting of a *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL T* and so on.

The text that is only outlines (like ) is also from the *Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols* block, starting with a *MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL L* etc.

With modern font rendering, it is often the case that one font face or even one font family does not contain glyphs for every possible codepoint. Most often, this is the case with Emoji. These missing glyphs are then substituted from a different font that has them—that is, if the application supports it. It appears that the Telegram client you’re using does not. So you see only the standard placeholder for missing glyphs: A box.

There are no specific fonts that you must use to get these characters. There are probably many fonts that have them.